# find all block devices (hdds and ssds) using sysfs

Tags: hard-disk, ssd, block-device, sysfs, nvme

Cant figure how to enumerate all physical disks, like hdds, ssds, NVMes and maybe flashdrives connected to machine and filter out all these loop devices, ram disks, cdrom and floppies.
I've checked out [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-block) and [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/stat.txt) to no avail.
In addition I would like to identify and distinguish remote device mapping(which are block devices) connected, like samba and such.
Any help is appreciated.

EDIT001: looks like  /sys/block/devicename/device/type would give me some useful information according to [this](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0602.1/1295.html)
the question is if I should look for `TYPE_DISK` only or there is anything else I should consider

EDIT002: Interestingly, but NVMe disk does not contain ./device/type file

Comment: Did you look in the sources of `lsblk`?

Comment: not yet. do you know I will find there something useful?

Comment: I imagine so, if the output of `lsblk` is what you are trying to get in your code.

Comment: not exactly, lsblk shows disks as well as rom/loop devices. I think the  /sys/block/devicename/device/type is the way to go

Comment: `sudo udevam settle && LC_ALL=C lsblk -o name,type | grep 'disk$'`?

Comment: Looks like it does what its supposed to do, but the question is about using sysfs. looks like I will have to check the `lsblk` source code